# Wrap around issue in a heap data structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, heap

I'm using a heap data structure (`std::priority_queue` or `boost::heap::binomial_heap`) in order to sort items using an `unsigned int`.

```
struct Item { uint32_t i; };
std::priority_queue<Item> myHeap;
```

I'm ascending the counter `i` for each item I `push()` into the heap, and when I `pop()` from the heap, because I'm sorting using `i` (which was not shown in this specific code example), I except to get the lowest `uint32_t`.

Is there a way to solve the wrap around problem nicely with the heap?;

When `i` gets to `2^32` it will wrap around back to `0`. This will cause the heap to give me item `0` instead of all the items that was prior to `0`.

Should I use other sorting technique?

Comment: Why not use `uint64_t`?

Comment: If you increment `i` for each item you push, do you really need a priority queue? Wouldn't a normal queue do then?

Comment: @MukulGupta the same problem is for uint64_t

Comment: @KarstenKoop I tried to make it more simple in my example, but I actually mean for a multithreaded env with atomic uint64_t

Comment: It appears that for your use-case, you would need a `bigint` class with custom comparator. In that case, it can never wrap around.

Comment: Custom comparator sounds good!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `uint32_t` or even `uint64_t` directly.

For indexing, you should `size_t` which is equal to the type return form the operator `sizeof`. So, if you are on `x64` platform it would adapt automatically.